# How to customize a regression line in an R graphics XY scatterplot?

Tags: r

I'd like to constrain an XY scatterplot regression line so that the line only goes through, or covers, the limits of the `x` variable range instead of running through the full extent of the graph plot.

**My problem**: When I use `abline(lm(y~x))` to create a regression line it extends across the entire plot.

Is there a way to constrain the range of my best fit line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `clip` :

```
plot(0:1,0:1)
usr <- par("usr")
clip(x1=0.5,x2=0.8,usr[3],usr[4])
abline(0,1)
do.call("clip", as.list(usr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `segments` function instead.

```
regression <- lm(y ~ x)
y_pred <- predict(regression)
which_x_max <- which.max(x)
which_x_min <- which.min(x)
segments(x0 = min(x), y0 = y_pred[which_x_min],
         x1 = max(x), y1 = y_pred[which_x_max])
```